# 301 redirect with .htaccess shows query string in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a redirect rule in `.htaccess`.

This is the rule:

```
Redirect 301 /ielts-sat http://www.example.com/ielts-training-in-kuwait
```

It redirects properly but the result page URL shows as `http://www.example.com/ielts-training-in-kuwait?/ielts-sat`.

How I remove this query string?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a cache issue? 301 redirection is permanent, browser will cache this redirection and ignore any further changes in `.htaccess` (it will not even hit the server).

Comment: yes this is not a cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below rule :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^ielts-sat$ /ielts-training-in-kuwait? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Did you enable the `RewriteEngine`? Try above code in different browser.

Comment: it is not redirecting now

Comment: Yes i enabled the rewrite engine. The above code redirection works properly, but still there is query string as ielts-sat. The redirected page url is http://www.apachia.com/ielts-training-in-kuwait?/ielts-sat

Comment: @SaabzCoder did you try to check it in Incognito window or in Private window?

Comment: Yes I tried it in private window and also in another browser but still showing the same.